# Ranking objects by absolute occurrence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries which contains contains floats. My goal is to rank these objects with considering the occurrence the duplicates.

### Example

If the highest value is `19.93` and it occurs three times in the raw list, we will have three `{"rank":1}`'s, and as we already have 3 ranked items, the item with `19.07` value will have `{"rank":4}` as there are three above ranked objects. (This is the logic how European soccer score rankings are calculated. I want to achieve the same)

```
{'value': {'total': 19.93}, 'rank': 1}
{'value': {'total': 19.93}, 'rank': 1}
{'value': {'total': 19.93}, 'rank': 1}
{'value': {'total': 19.07}, 'rank': 4}
{'value': {'total': 18.24}, 'rank': 5}
{'value': {'total': 18.24}, 'rank': 5}
{'value': {'total': 18.24}, 'rank': 5}
{'value': {'total': 17.15}, 'rank': 8}
{'value': {'total': 16.8}, 'rank': 9}
{'value': {'total': 16.8}, 'rank': 9}
{'value': {'total': 16.8}, 'rank': 9}
```

But instead of the above, my code gives me:

```
{'value': {'total': 19.93}, 'rank': 1}
{'value': {'total': 19.93}, 'rank': 1}
{'value': {'total': 19.93}, 'rank': 1}
{'value': {'total': 18.24}, 'rank': 3}
{'value': {'total': 18.24}, 'rank': 3}
{'value': {'total': 18.24}, 'rank': 3}
{'value': {'total': 19.07}, 'rank': 4}
{'value': {'total': 17.15}, 'rank': 5}
{'value': {'total': 16.8}, 'rank': 6}
{'value': {'total': 16.8}, 'rank': 6}
{'value': {'total': 16.8}, 'rank': 6}
```

What I basically do is creating a unique list from the values, track the occurrence of the previous objects and add it to the current `rank`. What am I doing wrong?

```
#########################
# actual code 
import random

def rank_lista(ordered_list):
    vals = []
    # add all values into a list
    for list_item in ordered_list:
        try:
            vals.append(list_item['value']['total'])
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)

    
    unique_values = sorted(list(set(vals)))

    sorted_list = []
    for ooo in reversed(list(unique_values)):
        sorted_list.append(ooo)

    unique_values = []
    unique_values = sorted_list

    print ('sorted unique values:', unique_values)
    
    
    for ordered_list_item in ordered_list:
        try:
            val = ordered_list_item['value']['total']

            if unique_values.index(val) == 0:
                ordered_list_item['rank'] = unique_values.index(val)+1
            
            elif unique_values.index(val) == 1:
                previous_value_index = 0
                previous_value_count = vals.count(unique_values[previous_value_index])
                ordered_list_item['rank'] = 1 + previous_value_count
            else:
                previous_value_index = unique_values.index(val)-1
                previous_value_count = vals.count(unique_values[previous_value_index])
                ordered_list_item['rank'] = (previous_value_index + 1) + previous_value_count

        except Exception as e:
            print (e,2)



    return ordered_list


def create_random_list():
    unique_rounded_floats = list(set(round(random.uniform(1, 20), 2) for _ in range(9)))
    floats_with_duplicates = [item for sublist in [[float_] * 3 for float_ in unique_rounded_floats] for item in sublist]
    other_floats = [round(random.uniform(1, 20), 2) for _ in range(11)]
    result_array = floats_with_duplicates + other_floats

    arr = []
    for r in result_array:
        obj = {}
        obj['value'] = {'total':r}
        arr.append(obj)

    return arr

random_list = create_random_list()
print (random_list)

result_list = sorted(rank_lista(random_list), key=lambda d: float(d['rank']), reverse = False)   

for res in result_list:
    print (res)
```

Comment: Why do you have 5,5,5,6 and not 5,5,5,8?

Comment: @mozway It was incorrect, edited it. You were right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple loop, keeping track of the previous value and incrementing the rank if the value changes from an [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
prev = None # this must be different from a number

# for each dictionary in descending order of values
for i, d in enumerate(sorted(random_list,
                key=lambda x: x['value']['total'],
                reverse=True), start=1):
    # if the value changes, update the rank
    if d['value']['total'] != prev:
        rank = i
    # assign the rank
    d['value']['rank'] = rank
    prev = d['value']['total']
```

Output:

```
[{'value': {'total': 19.93}, 'rank': 1},
 {'value': {'total': 19.93}, 'rank': 1},
 {'value': {'total': 19.93}, 'rank': 1},
 {'value': {'total': 19.07}, 'rank': 4},
 {'value': {'total': 18.24}, 'rank': 5},
 {'value': {'total': 18.24}, 'rank': 5},
 {'value': {'total': 18.24}, 'rank': 5},
 {'value': {'total': 17.15}, 'rank': 8},
 {'value': {'total': 16.8}, 'rank': 9},
 {'value': {'total': 16.8}, 'rank': 9},
 {'value': {'total': 16.8}, 'rank': 9}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this using `groupby`. So, first, sort by the total:

```py
random_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['value']['total'])
```

Then, you can mutate the dictionaries in-place as you iterate over the groupby object, starting with a rank of 1, and increasing the rank by the length of the group:

```py
import itertools

rank = 1

# Note, grouping key same as sorting key
for _, g in itertools.groupby(random_list, lambda x:x['value']['total']):
    group_length = 0
    for d in current_group:
        group_length += 1
        d['value']['rank'] = rank
    rank += group_length
```

Starting with a list:

```
[{'value': {'total': 1.79}},
 {'value': {'total': 1.79}},
 {'value': {'total': 1.79}},
 {'value': {'total': 2.28}},
 {'value': {'total': 2.28}},
 {'value': {'total': 2.28}},
 {'value': {'total': 5.46}},
 {'value': {'total': 5.46}},
 {'value': {'total': 5.46}},
 {'value': {'total': 10.21}},
 {'value': {'total': 10.21}},
 {'value': {'total': 10.21}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.67}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.67}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.67}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.78}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.78}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.78}},
 {'value': {'total': 16.19}},
 {'value': {'total': 16.19}},
 {'value': {'total': 16.19}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.82}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.82}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.82}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.66}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.66}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.66}},
 {'value': {'total': 4.78}},
 {'value': {'total': 2.34}},
 {'value': {'total': 13.18}},
 {'value': {'total': 13.76}},
 {'value': {'total': 14.85}},
 {'value': {'total': 4.6}},
 {'value': {'total': 19.03}},
 {'value': {'total': 13.79}},
 {'value': {'total': 6.97}},
 {'value': {'total': 16.01}},
 {'value': {'total': 4.81}}]
```

This got turned into:

```
[{'value': {'total': 1.79, 'rank': 1}},
 {'value': {'total': 1.79, 'rank': 1}},
 {'value': {'total': 1.79, 'rank': 1}},
 {'value': {'total': 2.28, 'rank': 4}},
 {'value': {'total': 2.28, 'rank': 4}},
 {'value': {'total': 2.28, 'rank': 4}},
 {'value': {'total': 2.34, 'rank': 7}},
 {'value': {'total': 4.6, 'rank': 8}},
 {'value': {'total': 4.78, 'rank': 9}},
 {'value': {'total': 4.81, 'rank': 10}},
 {'value': {'total': 5.46, 'rank': 11}},
 {'value': {'total': 5.46, 'rank': 11}},
 {'value': {'total': 5.46, 'rank': 11}},
 {'value': {'total': 6.97, 'rank': 14}},
 {'value': {'total': 10.21, 'rank': 15}},
 {'value': {'total': 10.21, 'rank': 15}},
 {'value': {'total': 10.21, 'rank': 15}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.67, 'rank': 18}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.67, 'rank': 18}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.67, 'rank': 18}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.78, 'rank': 21}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.78, 'rank': 21}},
 {'value': {'total': 12.78, 'rank': 21}},
 {'value': {'total': 13.18, 'rank': 24}},
 {'value': {'total': 13.76, 'rank': 25}},
 {'value': {'total': 13.79, 'rank': 26}},
 {'value': {'total': 14.85, 'rank': 27}},
 {'value': {'total': 16.01, 'rank': 28}},
 {'value': {'total': 16.19, 'rank': 29}},
 {'value': {'total': 16.19, 'rank': 29}},
 {'value': {'total': 16.19, 'rank': 29}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.66, 'rank': 32}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.66, 'rank': 32}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.66, 'rank': 32}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.82, 'rank': 35}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.82, 'rank': 35}},
 {'value': {'total': 17.82, 'rank': 35}},
 {'value': {'total': 19.03, 'rank': 38}}]
```